# Can Forceful Drag move Multiple Creatures?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, forced-movement, grapple

> **Forceful Drag**: You move your speed. For each square you move, you slide a creature grabbed by you 1 square to a square adjacent to you. The creature remains grabbed, and you do not provoke an opportunity attack from the grabbed creature for this movement. At the end of the move, you can end the grab to knock the creature prone.

This power for the Fighter has no Target, as such, assume you have a creature grabbed in both hands. Can you:

> A. Move Both creatures, as long as they remain within Reach (*i.e. Sliding extra squares*) during the movement
>
> B. Choose only a single Creature Grabbed to move, dropping Grab on other creature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's neither of those.**

Here's the key phrase:

> For each square you move, you slide a creature grabbed by you 1 square to a square adjacent to you.

At *each* square along your route, you slide any *one* of the creatures you have grabbed 1 square to a square adjacent to you. If you can keep both the creatures you have grabbed in range of you in this fashion, then you can move them both with you.

This *does* allow you to bring both grabbed foes with you, **if** you take a somewhat zig-zaggy route, so that each square you move keeps you adjacent to one of the two targets and you use the slide to bring the other back next to you. See the crude depiction using Excel & MS Paint below for an example:

[image: demonstration of zig-zag drag route]

In practice this style of movement will effectively cut your move speed in half, and will be difficult to use if there are any obstacles along your planned route.

Comment: Perhaps my wording on the question was off, but answer A is exactly what you are explaining here. I was mostly looking to see if you could move multiple creatures or not. Sure you have to break it up with the movement, but that is a non-issue in the grand scheme of things. I am going to Declare this the answer, but it is to note that selection A. is correct, just not elaborated on how much movement is all.

Comment: @OmnifariousGrey Ah, the use of the phrase "sliding extra squares" made me think you were talking about being able to move in a straight line and bring both grabbed foes with you, rather than having to do the zig-zag dance depicted above.

Comment: Yeah, some of the confuse there was on my part. Depending on the build you could have Controlling Advantage with this power (if Psion) and perform the Zig Zag easier than expected, or if your Reach was greater the lagging behind would not matter. Those were some of the circumstances I considered, but poorly tried to add those in for a simple answer. Thanks again.